# Where does the Mac version of the iPhone Configuration Utility store its data?

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management, apple-configurator

I am using the iPhone Configuration Utility to set up some iPads. I'm just setting up some web clippings and one wireless network and see that the utility is keeping a nice record of all the serial numbers as I attach them and install the same profile.

The export function doesn't seem to save this data so I'm wondering where it is stored so perhaps I can get it into a spreadsheet or other format other than a screen capture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~/Library/MobileDevice/Devices

The files appear to be stored as a plist with the device's UDID as the name.